# Smart cropping for ImageViews in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, imageview, crop

I'm looking for an automatic croppping tool for ImageViews in Android, that would crop the image in ImageView in runtime in a content-aware way.
This is also called Smart Crop or something. Here is an [example](https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop.js) for Javascript.

Is there a similar library with those smart crop algorythms implemented for Android ImageViews?
The idea of how it should work:

1. Getting the actual width-height of ImageView on the screen of the device in runtime.
2. Smart-cropping of the original image (or setting the positioning of the image, as if it's in the background) in a content-aware way (like, center on faces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using picasso (glide or fresco). This library crop images detecting faces supported on [google's vision service](https://developers.google.com/vision/)

https://github.com/aryarohit07/PicassoFaceDetectionTransformation

**Edit:**

There is a library based on smartcrop.js [here (smartcrop-android)](https://github.com/QuadFlask/smartcrop-android).
I haven't used already, but looikng to the example times. I kind of lower. A plus, it supports Rx.

Comment: Thank you. The PicassoFaceDetectionTransformation looks promising, but only for face recognition, at least as it states in the features (If no face is detected, it will fallback to CENTER CROP.) So, it won't work for other cases, inanimate objects.

Comment: I know, I updated my answer with a library based on smartcrop.js